# How to solve this onclick awkwardness?

Tags: javascript, onclick, onblur

[**http://jsfiddle.net/wmuYq/**](http://jsfiddle.net/wmuYq/)

I want to eliminate an awkwardness: the user has to click the submit button twice to submit the text.

What should I do to make it work with one click?

Comment: Where should I move the button? @James

Comment: inline JavaScript and CSS? *sigh*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `onmousedown` event on the submit button to submit the form:

```
document.getElementById("submitButton").onmousedown = function() {
   this.form.submit();
}
```

For the above example to work, you would need to give the button an ID. Also, you would need to change the name of the submit button from "submit" to something else, because otherwise it overwrites the `submit` property of the `form` element.

This works because the `mousedown` event will be triggered on the button before the `blur` event is triggered by the `textarea`.

Here's a working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/wmuYq/4/).

Answer (score 2):

You can set a timeout: http://jsfiddle.net/wmuYq/1/

```
document.getElementById("text1").onblur = function () {
   var target = this;
   setTimeout( function () {
        target.style.height='36px';
   }, 250);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well for one thing you have no form, so I am not sure how it submits at all.

Wrap your code in a form and add an action and it should work fine :-)

Comment: I am using a form, I just added the textarea and the submit code to JSFIDDLE

Comment: The problem is that if you focus the `textarea`, then try to click the button, the `blur` event fires on the `textarea` and the button moves, so it doesn't register the click.

Comment: @Akos -- add your full code or else we cannot help you and that fiddle is useless..

Comment: @Neal - I think it is the issue. Here's the same fiddle with the `form` added. Remove the event handlers from the `textarea` and click the button, and it will work: http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/wmuYq/3/

Answer (score 0):

This might work.  *Untested*

Remove the `onblur` event from the `textarea` and place it as on `onclick` on the `input`

```
onclick="document.getElementById('text1').style.height='36px'"
```

Revised fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/wmuYq/2/